# Legrand Orange book -errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, sectioning, report, format

I am using the Legrand Orange Book & compiling it using pdfLatex. I get the following issues:

1. Undefined control sequence.

   ```
   \@makechapterhead ...mdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter 
                                                    \begin {tikzpicture}[remem...
   l.296 \chapter{chapter1}
   ```

   The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined

2. Undefined control sequence.

   ```
   \@makechapterhead ... ,-9cm) node {\if@mainmatter 
                                                    \thechapter .  \fi #1\strut...
   l.296 \chapter{chapter1}
   ```

   The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
3. Extra `\else`.

   ```
   \@makechapterhead ...}}; \end {tikzpicture} \else 
                                                     \begin {tikzpicture}[remem...
   l.296 \chapter{chapter1}

   I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
   ```
4. Extra `\fi`.

   ```
   \@makechapterhead ...; \end {tikzpicture} \fi \fi 
                                                     \par \vspace *{270\p@ }}
   l.296 \chapter{chapter1}

   I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
   ```

5)Extra `\fi`.

```
   \NR@chapter ...chapterhead {#2}\@afterheading \fi 
                                                  
   l.296 \chapter{chapter1}
                            
   I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
```

These errors are recurring for almost each chapter.

The CHAPTER HEADINGS part of the structure.tex file is this:

```
---------------------------------------
CHAPTER HEADINGS
--------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    chaptertitle/.style={
    %   line width = 2pt ,
    %   rounded corners = 15pt ,
    %   draw = blue ,
    %   fill = white ,
    %   fill opacity = 1 ,
    %   inner sep = 15pt ,
        text = black,
        node font = \huge\sffamily\bfseries ,
        text width = \paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-10pt ,
        align = left
    }
}


% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by  Christian Hupfer

\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.north west)
        {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
            \draw[anchor=west,chaptertitle] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.7,inner sep=23pt]{\strut\makebox[44cm]{}};
            \draw[anchor=west,chaptertitle] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node {\if@mainmatter\thechapter. \fi#1\strut};
            \end{tikzpicture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
        \draw[anchor=south west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.7,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
        \draw[anchor=south west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
        \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
%\draw[anchor=south west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=1pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.7,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
%\draw[anchor=south west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am making some mistake in the structure.tex file, but can't figure out....
I have put only a part of the structure file. If required I can put in both structure.tex and main.tex completely. But i guess they'd occupy a whole lot of space here.
The structure file is a modification of the original template as per the formatting requirements of my university.

Can you please help me sort out these errors? Thank You.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You've provided several code snippets and a number of error messages. However, there's still a lot of information that's missing. Please augment your code snippets to make them [minimally compilable](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), so that others can replicate the errors (and, hopefully, suggest fixes).

Comment: Several remaks : 1) Give the link to the documents in your question. 2) How did you compile with Overleaf or with your system ? 3) Have you modified the template or the texts? 4) I've just compiled the sources with lualatex and TL pretest 2024 without any problem.

Comment: I downloaded the folder and compiled the `main.tex` file directly without modifying anything.

Comment: Comment all your modifications and compile to check if everything is fine. Then, one by one, uncomment your modification and compile to find which one raises the error.

Comment: you have not shown any relevant code but the error means you are using book level commands like `\mainmatter` and `\chapter` when using an `article` level class that does not have chapters.

Comment: @Mico  Would putting the structure.tex  and main.tex  files here be of any help to understand the errors and fix them? Please let me know.

Comment: @SDe - I don't know. For sure, I have no idea why you're redefining `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`.

Comment: @AlainMatthes I have had to modify the following files : main.tex and structure.tex Apart from this I have added .tex files as chapters

Comment: @Mico let me check with the original \@makechapterhead  &   \@makeschapterhead  and then get back

Comment: @NBur i will certainly go through the commenting and commenting part.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I am using 'report'  instead of article or book. And I  add chapters.

Comment: @SDe but you are showing no code so we have to guess. If you provided an example someone could debug. But essentially my previous comment holds. `report` does not have a `\mainmatter` command. `book` does and you are using code assuming `\mainmatter` is definend.

Comment: presumably in report it's all mainmatter so replace `\if@mainmatter` by `\iftrue` I would guess

Comment: replacing \if@mainmatter by \iftrue worked and I got rid of the \@mainmatter errors. But some other issues are there:

Comment: replacing \if@mainmatter by \iftrue worked and I got rid of the \@mainmatter errors. But some other issues are there:      1)   Package biblatex Warning: 'babel' option is deprecated. Please use 'autolang' instead.    2) Package fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is useless on input line 182.       3)   Package hyperref Warning: Option `backref' has already been used, setting the option has no effect on input line 593.      4)  Package hyperref Warning: Option `pagebackref' has already been used, setting the option has no effect on input line 593.

Comment: 5)   Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperindex' has already been used, setting the option has no effect on input line 593.     6)   Package hyperref Warning: Option `bookmarks' has already been used, setting the option has no effect on input line 593.       7)   Package biblatex Warning: Load 'inputenc' before biblatex.        8)    Package biblatex Warning: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing. Loading 'csquotes' recommended.     Is there any way to post the structure file here?

Comment: What changes are further required to get rid of errors 1 to 8 and get the pdf file output?